# How to filter ng-repeat data based on true false condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

sorry if this has been solved before, but I can't find an asnwer to it.

I am trying to sort an ng-repeat according to the selection on radio buttons,
but I simply can't figure how to hide and show the items in the ng-repeat.

An example:

html:

```
<form>
 <label><input type="radio" name="generic" />all</label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="generic" />offline</label>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="channel in controller.channelArray>
 <div>{{channel.name}}</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
channelArray = [];
pushStreams();

function pushStreams(data) {
 channelArray.push(data)
}
```

Now, this is just an example, and I haven't tested this code, but it works in my real code.
I just want to know, assuming the data contains a status variable that is either false a true, how to show all (both false and true) and how to filter out trues if I select the offline radio button.

Hope this is clear enough, thanks!

Comment: `<div ng-if="channel.status">{{channel.name}}</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this , you can use `ng-if` directive.

> The ng-if directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}.

```
<div ng-repeat="channel in channels">
     <div ng-if="validate(channel)">{{channel.name}}</div>
</div>
```

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.check='All';
   $scope.channels=[{
     name:'a',
     status:true
   },{
     name:'b',
     status:false
   },{
     name:'c',
     status:false
   },{
      name:'d',
     status:true
   }];
   
   $scope.validate=function(channel){
      switch($scope.check){
        case 'All':
           return true;
        case 'Offline':
           return !channel.status;
        case 'Online':
           return channel.status;
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl"> 
     <label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="check" value="All" />all</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="check" value="Offline" />offline</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="check" value="Online" />online</label>
    <div ng-repeat="channel in channels">
         <div ng-if="validate(channel)">{{channel.name}}</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. 

Ah yes, but this seems to target the data directly. I want to show/hide based on the the radio buttons choice, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @MCMowgli, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Works very well, just one addition, how do I check for a third option?

All, offline, online?

Comment: Give me an example, @MCMowgli.

Comment: The same example as above, but just with a third option. So it's show all, show only offline and show only online. (sorry, I didn't add it at once)

Comment: Thanks!! I figured it out by using a if else if hell structure, but this is much more elegant. THanks for the support!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="all" checked />all</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="offline" />offline</label>
</form>

<div ng-if="all" ng-repeat="channel in controller.channelArray">
<div>{{channel.name}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-if="offline" ng-repeat="channel in controller.channelArray | filter :{status:true}">
<div>{{channel.name}}</div>
</div>
```

you can use filters for that and if all means the first div will display and if you click on offline means the second div will display for the status true if you want to change the status the change the filter value also

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add `ng-model` directive's and `value` attributes to your radio buttons. The value will get stored in the `main.selectedFilter` variable (where it can be used in the filter later).

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <form>
     <label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="main.selectedFilter" value="All" />all</label>
     <label><input type="radio" name="generic" ng-model="main.selectedFilter" value="Offline" />Offline</label>
    </form>

    <div ng-repeat="channel in main.channelArray | filter : main.myFilterFunction ">
      <div>{{ channel.name }}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.selectedFilter = "All";

  vm.channelArray = [
    {
      name:'Channel One',
      status:true
    },
    {
      name:'Channel Two',
      status:true
    },
    {
      name:'Channel Three',
      status:false
    },
    {
      name:'Channel Four',
      status:true
    }
 ];

  vm.myFilterFunction = function(value){
    return (vm.selectedFilter === "All") || (!value.status);
  }

});
```

[**Example Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1jD5yWeHdZKXOoA9l4zu?p=preview)